# How to make app change to foreground from background programmatically in react-native?

Tags: react-native

As the title, how can we start a react-native app from background to foreground, like we tap on push notification, it will show the app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal library it is easy to use and you can even specify what screen you want to open within your app with the

> opened event listener

```
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', (data) => {
          if (data.notification.payload.title === 'New mensaje!') { 
              this.props.pushNewRoute('chat'); // open specific app screen (Redux)
          }
    });
```